# Doubts on symmetric and a skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

Given two following statements:

$1.$ "The diagonal elements of a skew-symmetric matrix are all zero."
$2.$ "A real/complex square matrix can be uniquely expressed as the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix."

As per my knowledge, these two statements are true. But I have a small doubt, **Do these two statements hold every time ?** or there are some cases where they don't.

Actually I saw somewhere that "these are not true if the ground field F be of characteristic $2$". But they doesn't provide any further details. So if any one has any point about my doubt, please provide me the same.

Comment: Indeed, by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1573310/949989) for a field with characteristic 2, statement 1 is not true.

Comment: I also mention the same in my last paragraph @KurtG.

Comment: So we agree. To show item 1 take a diagonal element $x$ of a skew-symmetric matrix. It must satisfy $-x=x$ which implies $x=0$ unless the field has characteristic 2.

Comment: So by this property, in the ground field F be of characteristic $2$, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is a skew-symmetric matrix. Right ?

Comment: '@nmasanta' : Absolutely. And to make things worse. It is symmetric *and* skew-symmetric.

Comment: Is $\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&0\cr}$ the sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric over a field of characteristic two?

Comment: In fact with characteristic 2, neither 1 nor 2 is true.

Comment: @GerryMyerson . No and thanks ! Write $(m_{ij})$ for this matrix. If there existed a symmetric matrix $(s_{ij})$ and a skew-symmetrix matrix $(a_{ij})$ s.t. $m_{ij}=s_{ij}+a_{ij}$ then $1=m_{12}+m_{21}=s_{12}+s_{21}=s_{12}+s_{12}=0$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi . Agreed .